Equivalence of Conditional Probabilities and Independence Under Sub-$\sigma$ $\sigma$-Algebras
Let $\mathscr{C}_1, \mathscr{C}_2, \mathscr{C}_3$ be sub-$\sigma$-algebras of some measurable space, and define $\mathscr{C}_{ij} = \sigma(\mathscr{C}_i \cup \mathscr{C}_j)$ for $1 \leq i, j \leq 3$. I am trying to prove the equivalence of the following two statements:

$\mathbb{P}(A_3 \mid \mathscr{C}_{12}) = \mathbb{P}(A_3 \mid \mathscr{C}_2)$ for all $A_3 \in \mathscr{C}_3$.
$\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_3 \mid \mathscr{C}_2) = \mathbb{P}(A_1 \mid \mathscr{C}_2) \mathbb{P}(A_3 \mid \mathscr{C}_2)$ for all $A_1 \in \mathscr{C}_1$ and $A_3 \in \mathscr{C}_3$.

Here are my attempt at proving $1\implies 2$:
Since $\mathscr{C}_{12} \subset \mathscr{C}_2$, we can write:
$$
\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_3 \mid \mathscr{C}_2) = \mathbb{P}\left( \mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_3 \mid \mathscr{C}_{12}) \mid \mathscr{C}_2 \right).
$$
Using the assumption in (1) and the fact that $A_1 \in \mathscr{C}_1$, it seems reasonable to treat $A_1$ and $A_3$ as conditionally independent given $\mathscr{C}_{12}$. (I am not sure of this statement)
This gives:
$$
\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_3 \mid \mathscr{C}_{12}) = \mathbb{P}(A_1 \mid \mathscr{C}_{12}) \mathbb{P}(A_3 \mid \mathscr{C}_{12}) = \mathbb{P}(A_1 \mid \mathscr{C}_{12}) \mathbb{P}(A_3 \mid \mathscr{C}_2).
$$
Substituting this back in, we get:
$$
\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_3 \mid \mathscr{C}_2) = \mathbb{P}\left( \mathbb{P}(A_1 \mid \mathscr{C}_{12}) \mathbb{P}(A_3 \mid \mathscr{C}_2) \mid \mathscr{C}_2 \right) = \mathbb{P}(A_1 \mid \mathscr{C}_2) \mathbb{P}(A_3 \mid \mathscr{C}_2).
$$
I'm not entirely confident in the step where I assume conditional independence, especially in the context of (\sigma)-algebras. It feels a bit hand-wavy, and I’m unsure if there’s a more rigorous way to justify this using measure-theoretic tools.
Some Questions:

Does this proof make sense, or am I missing something crucial?
I’ve been learning about conditional probability through conditional expectations, but I’m struggling to apply that formalism here. Could someone explain how to rigorously connect these ideas in this context?
Is there a connection between this problem and regular conditional probabilities that I should explore?
How to prove $2\implies 1$? If my prove of $1\implies 2$ is right, how to treat $1\implies 2$ similar?

Any feedback or guidance would be really helpful! Thanks in advance.

Rather than $\Bbb P(\Bbb P(E\mid\mathscr C_{12})\mid\mathscr C_2))$, you want $\Bbb E(\Bbb P(E\mid\mathscr C_{12})\mid\mathscr C_2))$

The claim $\mathscr{C}_{12} \subset \mathscr{C}_2$ is wrong. Since $\mathscr{C}_2 \subset \mathscr{C}_1 \cup \mathscr{C}_2$, we should have $\mathscr{C}_2 \subset \mathscr{C}_{12}$ instead.
Regardless, because of $\mathscr{C}_2 \subset \mathscr{C}_{12}$, it is indeed true that
$$
    \mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_3 \mid \mathscr{C}_2) = \mathbb{P}\left( \mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_3 \mid \mathscr{C}_{12}) \mid \mathscr{C}_2 \right).
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
    \mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_3 \mid \mathscr{C}_2) = \mathbb{E}\left( \mathbb{E}(1_{A_1}1_{A_3} \mid \mathscr{C}_{12}) \mid \mathscr{C}_2 \right).
$$
Since $A_1 \in \mathscr{C}_{1} \subseteq \mathscr{C}_{12}$, we thus have
$$
      \mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_3 \mid \mathscr{C}_{12}) = \mathbb{E}(1_{A_1}1_{A_3} \vert \mathscr{C}_{12}) = 1_{A_1}\mathbb{E}(1_{A_3} \vert \mathscr{C}_{12}) = 1_{A_1}\mathbb{E}(1_{A_3} \vert \mathscr{C}_2)
$$
Since $\mathbb{P}(A_3 \vert \mathscr{C}_2) \in \mathscr{C}_2$, therefore,
$$
   \mathbb{P}\left( \mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_3 \mid \mathscr{C}_{12}) \mid \mathscr{C}_2 \right) = \mathbb{E}(1_{A_1}\mathbb{E}(1_{A_3} \vert \mathscr{C}_2) \vert \mathscr{C}_2) = \mathbb{E}(1_{A_1} \vert \mathscr{C}_2)\mathbb{E}(1_{A_3} \vert \mathscr{C}_2) = \mathbb{P}(A_1 \vert \mathscr{C}_2)\mathbb{P}(A_3 \vert \mathscr{C}_2)
$$
So,
$$
     \mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_3 \mid \mathscr{C}_2) = \mathbb{P}(A_1 \vert \mathscr{C}_2)\mathbb{P}(A_3 \vert \mathscr{C}_2)
$$
For the reverse direction, we want to show that
$$
    \mathbb{P}(A_3 \vert \mathscr{C}_{12}) = \mathbb{P}(A_3 \vert \mathscr{C}_2) \ \forall A_3 \in \mathscr{C}_3
$$
or, equivalently, for every bounded, $\mathscr{C}_{12}$-measurable function $X$, we have that
$$
     \mathbb{E}(X \cdot 1_{A_3}) = \mathbb{E}(X \cdot \mathbb{P}(A_3 \vert \mathscr{C}_2))
$$
Let
$$
    \mathcal{H} = \{\text{ bounded and measurable function } X: \mathbb{E}(X \cdot 1_{A_3}) = \mathbb{E}(X \cdot \mathbb{P}(A_3 \vert \mathscr{C}_2))\}
$$
and
$$
    \mathcal{A} = \{G_{i_1} \cap G_{i_2} \cap \ldots G_{i_k}: k \in \mathbb{N}, i_k \in \{1, 2\}, \text{ and } G_{i_k} \in \mathscr{C}_{i_k}\}
$$
Then $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\pi$-system and $\mathscr{C}_{12} = \sigma(\mathcal{A})$. See this question
Hint for next step: Check necessary conditions and use the monotone class theorem for functions

Thank a lot for your reply! I’m curious, though, about your approach to establishing the $\pi$ system method to handle it.  Could you kindly share more about how you arrived at this idea? This seems the only way (or, the easiest?) to solve this problem (my teacher use this method, too), why?

@Night This is a really common way to tackle this kind of problem. You can see a lot of theorems can be solved using this machinery, see e.g Probability and Stochastics by Erhan Çinlar
